# Fluid FlexForms are not loaded after upgradding Fluid Content Engine to 4.2.3

Tags: typo3, fluid

All my custom fluid content element working fine. But today when i upgrade Fluid Content Engine extension to 4.2.3 my fluid flexform is not loaded. I think this is bug in new version of Fluid Content Engine 4.2.3.

I used Below Extensions in which its working fine.

- vhs               2.3.3
- flux              7.2.1
- fluidcontent      4.2.2
- fluidpages        3.2.3

And added below typoscript for fluid content rendering.

```
plugin.tx_mytemplate.view {
        templateRootPath = EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Private/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Private/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Private/Layouts/

    }

plugin.tx_fluidpages {
    collections.mytemplate {
        templateRootPath = EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Private/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Private/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
}

plugin.tx_fluidcontent {
    collections.mytemplate {
        templateRootPath = EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Private/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Private/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:mytemplate/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
}
```

And in ext.tables.php i added below code.

```
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey($_EXTKEY, 'Content');
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey($_EXTKEY, 'Page');
```

It works fine but after upgradding to Fluid Content Engine 4.2.3 fluid flexform is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an issue on github and a possible fix that you can apply yourself by removing line 22 in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`. The line you have to remove is

```
 --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance
```

You could of course also switch back to 4.2.2 and wait for a fix.

https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidcontent/issues/243